# Accessing a passed variable from JQuery to Rails controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this JQuery code:

```
    $("div.notification").live("click", function(){
        window.location=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
        var myId = $(this).attr("id");
        $.post("/videos/selected_notification.js", myId);
        return false;
    });
```

I want to be able to access `myId` from inside my controller that the post request hits. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `myId` value a name and you can pull it out of `params` just like any other POST parameter:

```
$.post("/videos/selected_notification.js", { id: myId });
```

And then, in the controller:

```
id = params['id'] # Or params[:id] since params is a HashWithIndifferentAccess
```

Comment: ahh nice... what if I'm not actually POSTing anything. Would that code be OK?

Comment: also would it not be `params[:id]`?

Comment: @Justin: Why would you by using `$.post` if you're not posting anything? You have to post something to get your data to the server (or use GET if that's more appropriate). Accessing `params` with the `:id` symbol or `'id'` string should work.

Comment: @Justin: `params` is actually a [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html), not a plain `Hash`. The keys are actually strings but `HashWithIndifferentAccess` converts symbols to strings for you.